# Kotlin Reflection Issue

Tags: java, reflection, kotlin

I have these methods declared in Java libraries:

Engine.java:

```
public <T extends EntitySystem> T getSystem(Class<T> systemType)
```

Entity.java:

```
public <T extends Component> T getComponent(Class<T> componentClass)
```

Now, I use these methods A LOT, and I would really like to use `MyComponent::class` (i.e. kotlin reflection) instead of the more verbose `javaClass<MyComponent>()` everywhere.

My `EntitySystem` and `Component` implementations are written in Kotlin.

So I thought I would create extension functions that take `KClasses` instead, but I am not quite sure how to make them work.

Something along the lines of...

```
public fun <C : Component> Entity.getComponent(type: KClass<out Component>): C {
    return getComponent(type.javaClass)
}
```

But this does not work for several reasons: The compiler says type inference failed, since `javaClass` returns `Class<KClass<C>>`. And I need `Class<C>`. I also don't know how to make the method properly generic.

Can anyone help me create these methods?

Comment: I have posted a new answer which is valid for current Kotlin and implements the inline function with reified type parameters as suggested by @bashor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the extension property [`java`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/-k-class/java.html) instead of `javaClass`.

Additionally You can improve your API with [reified type parameters](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) and rewrite your code like:

```
public inline fun <reified C : Component> Entity.getComponent(): C {
    return getComponent(C::class.java)
}
```

Comment: `public fun Engine.get<S : EntitySystem>(type: KClass<S>) : S {
 return getSystem(type.java)
}` seemed to do the trick

Comment: I have updated to the latest Kotlin (0.12.1230), and the kotlin.reflect.jvm does not seem to exist anymore? Anyone know if it has been renamed or something?

Comment: Never mind... the problem seemed to be that the Android Studio's intention to add kotlin-reflect did not update the build.gradle-file at all...

Comment: `javaClass<T>()` is deprecated, use `T::class` instead.

Answer (score 2):

In current Kotlin (1.0), the code would be simpler as:

```
public inline fun <reified C : Component> Entity.getComponent(): C {
    return getComponent(C::class)
}
```

And can be called:

```
val comp: SomeComponent = entity.getComponent()
```

Where type inference will work, reify the generic type parameter (including any nested generic parameters) and call the method, which then uses the type parameter as a class reference.